# How to:: Master-Master replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, percona, multi-master

I have setup Master-Master replication on two servers. Now, my question is that if I need to have the second master as only read-only, what should I do? I tried doing

`mysql> flush tables with read lock;`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

`mysql> set global read_only=ON;`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

But since this creates a read-lock in my 2nd master (Slave 1). The changes that I make in Master 1 is not propagated to Master 2 (Read-only).

What should I do such that - changes in Master 1 are getting updated to Master 2 but Master 2 should not be in write mode, Master-master(Active/Passive).
Is it possible to do this?

Regds

Comment: If everything is set up correctly then replication should continue to happen, even with a read lock in place. (also if anyone connects with the `super` privilege they can write to your master 2). That is exactly how our databases are set up.

Comment: No I tried. I set read lock in my 2nd master. I created a new database in Master 1. And I checked slave status in Master 2, it says it is on read-lock and behind the master and it isn't getting updated. Did I miss something out??

Comment: if you remove the read lock, does replication happen as you expect (from master 1 to Master 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Stop the slave on the first master

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
```

If the second master becomes a read only then the first master should no longer replicate from it.

2 Change the 2nd master's configuration to read only.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL READ_ONLY=1;
```

Add read_only=1 to my.cnf for the next restart

[Read Only variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only)

3 Unlock the tables on the second master

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

You don't need to lock tables on the second master (now slave)

4 Secure privileges

Redefine privileges on the 2nd master, follow this answer here : [Should a MySQL replication slave be set to read only?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30128/should-a-mysql-replication-slave-be-set-to-read-only)

5 Verify slave status on 2nd Master, now slave.

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host: 10.11.128.52
```

If the second master is not replicating then you may have to reinitialize the replication to the first master.

A. On first master, identify current log and position

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;

+------------------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB             | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      107 | base1, base2             |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

B. On second master now slave, reinitalize replication

```
Stop SLAVE ;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = '10.11.128.52', 
MASTER_USER = 'repli', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'repli', 
MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS = 107;
Start SLAVE;
```

C. Show status on second master(now slave)

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host: 10.11.128.52
```

Comment: Thanks, I reinitialized by updating the log-position as per A,B and C. It works fine. But what is your opinion, Master-Master is better or Master-Slave? I feel Master-Master has lesser downtime than Master-Slave when the first Master goes down. It is easier to point the application to second master(running in read only) as primary master rather than promoting the slave to master and then proceeing. your inputs?

Comment: What is the purpose of each server in your configuration?

Comment: Purpose is that I need to run Master-Slave or Master-Master for my application. I chose Master-master instead of Master-slave because the downtime in switching the application pointer would be less in case of master-master since I would need to promote slave to master in master-slave which would take more time. So my question is that is Master-master with 2nd master being passive better or should I keep it as both active?

Comment: Stick with master-master then as you would eliminate the need to run the change master command on the first master. You can still keep replication going and lock down your second server by restricting login access to it.

Comment: Okay but keeping master master with both active.. Is it risky? Even if i set auto increment is it risky to have both active?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by risky. If an insert is received by each master for the same table, the second insert will simply get the next increment value, n+1.

Comment: But that applies only when primary key is there on all the tables.. If not then it is a issue right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27416/discussion-between-craig-efrein-and-tesla747).

Comment: I have set only read-only =1 in the config file. Is that enough for a passive master? Or should I run also flush tables with read lock??